# For i = StartIndex To 1 Step -1 (Index was outside bounds of array for ( i- 1)

Tags: vb.net

how can I make a condition for my code to not to get out of range?

```
Dim StartIndex = TextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
For i = StartIndex To 0 Step -1
Dim strx = TextBox1.Lines(i - 1)
```

I mention that I also changed with `For i = StartIndex To 1 Step -1`, but it displays my values ​​wrong with one unit less. and I'm not sure if he wouldn't have errors like that.

basically I have to make this code work, without getting out of range. but which should work on `For i = StartIndex To 0 Step -1` if anyone can confirm to me that it has no errors on `For i = StartIndex To 1 Step -1` then I will leave him like that. it just shows me with one unit less what I need.

```
Dim strx = TextBox1.Lines(i - 1)
```

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger?

Comment: i think when i reaches the value 0, at i-1 it will be out of range. that's why I have to make a fix for it.

Comment: `dim lines = TextBox1.Lines.Reverse().ToArray() TextBox1.Lines = lines`. Otherwise, avoid to go down to index -1 (`Dim strx = TextBox1.Lines(i)`).

Comment: that's not good. for what I do, it must always be i + 1.

Comment: Then actually explain what is that you're trying to achieve instead of (or in addition to) how you tried to achieve it.

Comment: For one thing, don't keep using `TextBox1.Lines` over and over. That property creates a new array every time you access it, which is very inefficient. Start by assigning the property value to a variable and then use that variable multiple times, so that you use the same array every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Explicitly type your variables
2. Get the Lines property of the TextBox just once (outside of the loop)
3. Iterate from the length of the array (minus 1) to 1 instead of to 0

```vb
Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Lines
For i As Integer = lines.Length - 1 To 1 Step -1
    Dim strx As String = lines(i - 1)
Next
```

However, just briefly looking over your code it seems like you shouldn't iterate from the length of the array minus 1 since you're subtracting by 1 when you get the currently iterated item in the For/Next loop.